# Mistakes with Modal Pop up (display:none function in js)

Tags: javascript, html, popup, addeventlistener, simplemodal

I'm setting up a new personal website.

.Modal Pop up onclick on image, the modal pop up have to change the proprieties from display:none to display:flex.

I've modify my codes structure, in something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLWIYk0Sd38

but still don't work.

Here's a link to a CodePen [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/tta1eu/pen/gyGwOm):

https://codepen.io/tta1eu/pen/gyGwOm

```
document.getElementById('Avatar15').addEventListener("click", function() {
document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
```

});

```
document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: The problem is with `document.getElementById('Avatar15')` No such element with the id of `Avatar15` exists

Comment: i've just update the codePen! Love ur fast replied to that guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you need to show popup in the center while scrolling the page. Then, you have to change below CSS properties.

`.bg-modal{
    width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(63,191,63,0.64); position: fixed;
    top:0; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: none;

}`

In the reference, youtube video link has no scroll of the HTML page. When where the page has scroll then it should be use fixed property.

**Second Option:**
Add one class on the body as 'overflow: hidden' when where modal is show and remove that class when modal is hide/display none.

Comment: yes! loving solution, the main problem its still there, how should I set the js code to make the each single photo I clicked open in the pop up? ive to copy the function for every single photo or there is a smart solution?

Comment: Yes, you can use one function for all images. Check below URL
https://codepen.io/nsuyog-the-decoder/pen/mgBOGv

you can handle the click event from classname instead of elementById

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the link / button with the ID=Avatar15 that have the click event to display to popup

add to the HTML :

```
<a id="Avatar15">Click</a>
```

Comment: I've just update the CodePen, the ID=Avatar15 it's on the first photo

Comment: if i click the div with ID=Avatar15, looks ok and it's working. what excatly the problenm?.
why are you setting the ecent listener on each ID .... you can do it by class and getting the image src to display in the modal.

Comment: like: put the ID=Avatar15 not on the div class:child but only in the div class:overlays ,
and afterwards in the pop up can I open each single photo? 
I use the pop up like a "zoom" for each sigle photos and for more info about the photos.
I saw also a plug in like: FANCYBOX / but too complicate for now
but im still learing, maybe there is a easy way or some mistake that i can't see.

Comment: and a little other things is: Why th bg-modal (the rgba green bg) is set to  width: 100%; height: 100%; but it's not cover he full page, but it's not a big problem, i don't want to keep that bg color

Comment: 1) yes, something like, doesn't realt matters on which element you put the event listener ... important how to take the relevant image src to set in the img inside the modal popup and show it.
2) for the bg change the modal css from position absolute to position fixed.